# How I can convert a negative definite matrix to a positive definite?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices, positive-definite

If I have a negative definite matrix $A$, can I convert this matrix to a positive definite by taking columns $A$ of the negative eigenvalues?

Comment: not sure I understand the question but $-A$ is positive definite if $A$ is negative definite

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of what you want to do to $A$, but you could just multiply by $-1$. As an example take a diagonal matrix:

\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & \lambda_{2} & 0\\ 0 & 0 & \lambda_3 \end{bmatrix}

If you want to select some columns of $A$ you should select only the ones corresponding to positive eigenvalues (with the matrix in diagonal form) if you want a positive definite matrix.